# Multiple Token replacement php function correctly replaces the tokens with assigned widget but drops the content containing the tokens

Tags: php

I have a php function that replaces tokens with assigned content. The tokens are actually paths to the widgets: `{widgets/buttons/next-step.php}` which the function retrieves the widget via an `include();`.

The function successfully retrieves and renders the widgets, but the content the token is in is lost. I have tried numerous adjustments to the code without success. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

**Content Sample:**

```
    $content  = '<h1>Button</h1>{widgets/buttons/next-step.php}';
    $content  .= '<h1>Duscussion</h1>{widgets/discussions/altar-of-christ.php}';
    $content  .= '<h1>Build Altar Lab</h1>{widgets/labs/altar-of-christ-lab.php}';
```

All the `<h1>`s are dropped.

**PHP Function:**

```
function replaceTokens($content){

    # minimize content
    $content = str_replace("\r\n",'',str_replace("\t",'',$content));

    # run content through short code/widget preg match
    preg_match_all("'{(.*?)}'si", $content, $match); 

    # replace token with content
    foreach($match[1] as $val) {

        # rebuild token for str_replace()
        $token = '{'.$val.'}';      

        # get token content
        $this_content = include($val);

        # replace token with content
        $content = str_replace($token,$this_content,$content);
    }
    return $content;    
}
```

If I change `return $content;` to `echo $content;` the function renders each widget correctly and then under the widgets it returns each of the `<h1>` tags with the number `1` under each headline as follows:

**WIDGET 1**

**WIDGET 2**

**WIDGET 3**

**Button**

1

**Discussion**

1

**Build Altar Lab**

1

I understand what is happening but do not know how to resolve the issue...

The function simply includes and renders the widgets as it loops through the preg_match_all and then the `str_replace()` does not recognize `$this_content` and returns a `1` instead.

I have tried:

```
        ob_start();
        eval('?>'.file_get_contents($val).'<?php;');
        $this_content = ob_get_clean();
```

and:

```
 $this_content =file_get_contents($val);
```

Thinking the function needed just the code of the widgets and contain it within `$this_content` to allow `str_replace()` to function properly but the result is the same.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. https://3v4l.org/QQeiH perhaps there's an issue in the include files?

Comment: Each widget renders correctly... just no surrounding content. The server is running php 5.1 do you think that might be the issue?

Comment: It works fine on PHP 5.1 too... you can see all the `<h1>` in the output: https://3v4l.org/QQeiH

Comment: I created a simple widget file `<?php echo 'test'; ?>` and ran it again with no luck

Comment: Your widget file needs to `return` the value i.e. `<?php return 'test'; ?>`. See the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Comment: `<?php return 'test'; ?>` returns blank... it needs to be echoed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ISSUE RESOLVED:**

The function was rendering the execution of the php code and not passing the code itself. I simply changed the `.php` files to `.dat` files and then changed `$this_content = include($val);` to `$this_content = file_get_contents($val);` and then `return $content;` to `echo $content;`.

This allows the function to store the code itself in the `$this_content` variable, which in turn, allows the `$content = str_replace($token,$this_content,$content);` to do its job correctly.

I also improved the minimization of the `$content` variable at the top of the function.

The new code:

**Content Code:**

```
    $content  = '<h1>Button</h1>{widgets/buttons/next-step.dat}';
    $content  .= '<h1>Discussion</h1>{widgets/discussions/altar-of-christ.dat}';
    $content  .= '<h1>Build Altar Lab</h1>{widgets/labs/altar-of-christ-lab.dat}';


    echo '<div class="grid"><div class="row"><div class="col_12">';
    replaceTokens($content);
    echo '</div></div></div>';
```

**The Function:**

```
function replaceTokens($content){

    # minimize content
    $content = str_replace("\r",'',$content);
    $content = str_replace("\n",'',$content);
    $content = str_replace("\t",'',$content);

    # run content through short code/widget preg match
    preg_match_all("'{(.*?)}'si", $content, $match); 

    # replace token with content
    foreach($match[1] as $val) {

        # rebuild token for str_replace()
        $token = '{'.$val.'}';

        # store widget code
        $this_content = file_get_contents($val);

        # replace token with content
        $content = str_replace($token,$this_content,$content);

    }
    echo $content;  
}
```